# Common pattern for compiling the app version inside the executable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know that the application version in a Mac application is defined by the **Info.plist** file situated inside the bundle.

The application version number in my case is not only informative, it defines some behaviors in my app. **If someone edits this file, my application could break.** The fastest solution is to compile the app version inside the executable.

Is there a common pattern for compiling the app version inside the executable?

*The application version should be static/global IMHO.*

Comment: If your application is Code Signed then a user will not be able to modify the `Info.plist` file without breaking the app. Why would a user change the app version in the `Info.plist` anyway? This seems to be a very unlikely scenario.

Comment: Why are you leaving old behavior in your app subject to the version number? Why not just cut the old code out?

Comment: The point is, if my app relay on server, client and server should have synced behaviors. The user must update the app when the server updates, and my update routine have to relay on a solid version numbering. For now i created a NSString in my pch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your target's build settings, go to the Versioning category and change `Versioning System` from `None` to `Apple Generic`. Then, whenever you change the version of your application, change the `Current Project Version` setting. If you don't change the other build settings, then each build will generate a file called `$(PRODUCT_NAME)_vers.c` which contains two variables, defined as follows:

```
const unsigned char $(PRODUCT_NAME)VersionString[] = "@(#)PROGRAM:$(PRODUCT_NAME) PROJECT:$(PROJECT_NAME)-$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)\n";
const double $(PRODUCT_NAME)VersionNumber = (double)$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION);
```

For the version number, anything after the second decimal place is cut off so that it can be represented as a double. i.e., 1.2.3 is stored as 1.2. Both variables are also given the `used` attribute so that they won't be removed if you don't use them.

In order to use these variables, you need to declare them as extern in the files where they will be used. You can either do this in every file which will use them, or create a header with these declarations and include that in your files. The declarations should look like this:

```
extern const unsigned char $(PRODUCT_NAME)VersionString[];
extern const double $(PRODUCT_NAME)VersionNumber;
```

Then you can use them like normal variables.

Comment: how can i call these constants inside the app?

Comment: You will need to declare them as an extern. I'll add this to my post to show how.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%f", MyAppVersionNumber);` => 0.0000 no way to get the version number :)

Comment: @killianc Did you change the `Current Project Version` build setting, right above the `Versioning System` one?